# Valid sitecore query - wrong xpath query

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

why does valid sitecore query:
/sitecore/content/#My tree#/MyItems/*[contains(@@name, 'thename')]
in xpath results to: Expression must evaluate to a node-set. Using sitecore developer center / xpath builder. Wanted to modify the query to use in code.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Sitecore Query, and isn't valid xpath. You can only use it in certain places within Sitecore (such as field sources) as well as within CodeBehind files.

There's a PDF document explaining it [on the SDN](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/developer/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query001.pdf)

Comment: adam it's not a fast query but a normal sitecore query. Fast queries start with fast://